# Karma AngularJs Cancel/mock Timeout E2E

Tags: javascript, testing, angularjs, mocking, karma-runner

In angular I have a service object which animates page transitions.  The problem is the animation is making karma/testacular E2E tests run very slowly.  The code looks like the following:

```
.factory('Animator', function($timeout, $location, $rootScope){
        return {
            animate: function(animationVariable, animationType, callback){
                $rootScope[animationVariable] = animationType + " animated";
                $timeout(
                    function(){
                        $rootScope[animationVariable] = "";
                        if(callback) { callback() }
                    },1300)
                ;
            }
        }
    })
```

How Can I mock out the animation functionality so that it is skipped when running E2E tests in karma.

Answer (score 0):

Karma is able to start, but is unable to execute tests if any of your source files use Angular $timeout service. If you wish to still test your application, you will need to remove any references to the $timeout service or write your own.

**Source:** [Vojta Jína](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/e2CfWnHjvfU/h9xA5lBkKjsJ)

Comment: The tests run.  The problem is that the timeout is taking too much time during the test.

Comment: If you set Karma's logLevel to LOG_DEBUG, do you see the tests attempt to execute, or does it just hang after it's finished loading all of the required resources on your page?

Comment: It runs fine just slowly because of the animation which is why I want to mock it out somehow.